# App install attribution

Tags: facebook-analytics

I would like to attribute in app events to the mobile ads run on facebook. The FB SDK has been integrated. Is there a way to capture and log campaign id as a parameter with the in app events? Or a way to post back the event info to Facebook? The larger question is to figure out a way of attributing app installs to the facebook install ads

Comment: There must be described  in Facebook API Documentation

Answer (score 0):

Facebook latest SDK is taken care of it automatically, basically attributing app installs to the facebook install ads. One will be able to slice and dice the events in Facebook Analytics based on campaign. Take in mind currently it works only with Facebook campaigns.